# WebSphere: boundedbuffer.waitGet_ is using up most of the CPU

Tags: java, websphere

I used jvisualVM on some WAS 7.0.0.19 programs - and sampled the CPU. It appears that a huge chunk of it goes to boundedbuffer.waitGet_().

Can you explain if this is normal?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there any application running? Is it a default was installation? Is it happening whenever the application is called?

Comment: It happends during the lifetime of a WebSphere application server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is actually (kind of) normal. These timings are caused by threads in the following state:

```
"Deferrable Alarm : 0" - Thread t@35
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <6bc66bc6> (a com.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer$GetQueueLock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer.waitGet_(BoundedBuffer.java:187)
        - locked <6bc66bc6> (a com.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer$GetQueueLock)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer.poll(BoundedBuffer.java:609)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool.getTask(ThreadPool.java:899)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1653)
```

These are simply worker threads that are idle and waiting for new tasks. They don't consume any CPU time. For some reason, VisualVM includes threads in this state in the profiling data instead of just ignoring them (as it appears to do with other waiting threads).

If you look at the data shown by VisualVM you may also notice that threads in this state only contribute to the "Self time" value, but not to "Self time (CPU)". You can actually get a more realistic picture of the CPU usage of your WebSphere process if you sort on "Self time (CPU)".

Comment: Great. I'm going to check it and if this is the case - You'll get the bounty. Thank you.